# instruction prallelism using OpenMp

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize the below code using OpenMp. This code belongs to Encryption algorithm where output of each iteration is input to next iteration. Therefore i think that i can not parallelize this for loop due to dependency of rounds. But i want to parallelize  each part of the instruction
y += **((z<<4)+k[0])**  ^   **(z+sum)**  ^   **((z>>5)+k[1])**  using separate threads and get XOR finally . I tried to insert openMp directive inside loop but it takes longer time. Please correct me where i am doing wrong.

```
for(n=0;n<32;n++)
{
sum += delta;

#pragma omp parallel
y += ((z<<4)+k[0]) ^ (z+sum) ^ ((z>>5)+k[1]);

z += ((y<<4)+k[2]) ^ (y+sum) ^ ((y>>5)+k[3]);

}
```

Comment: You are really going wrong at the outset, choosing OpenMP for this type of application.  Even if you successfully parallelise the computations of `y` and  of `z` that you show you are very unlikely to achieve any speedup; there are simply too few operations to outweigh the overheads.  A better approach for parallelising most cryptographic algorithms is to implement some kind of *software pipeline*.

Comment: I should have finished my previous comment with this: A better approach for parallelising most cryptographic algorithms is to implement some kind of *software pipeline* but OpenMP is not designed for, nor easy to adapt to, that type of parallel computing.